# Ionic 2 to 3 Update Gulp ERROR

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gulp, updates, gulp-sass

So i upgraded to Ionic 3 and got this Error when i perform ionic serve:

> [ERROR] Gulpfile not found: .\gulpfile.js
>           You can set the gulpFile attribute in ionic.config.json for custom
>           Gulpfile locations, otherwise the default Ionic Gulpfile can be
>           downloaded from
>           https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-base/blob/master/gulpfile.js
>
> ```
>     Or, if you no longer use gulp, you can remove the CLI Gulp Plugin:
>
>     npm uninstall --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-gulp@latest
> ```

My Package.json looks like this:

> {   "dependencies": {
>       "@angular/common": "4.1.2",
>       "@angular/compiler": "4.1.2",
>       "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.2",
>       "@angular/core": "4.1.2",
>       "@angular/forms": "4.1.2",
>       "@angular/http": "4.1.2",
>       "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.2",
>       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.2",
>       "@ionic-native/core": "3.10.2",
>       "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.10.2",
>       "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.10.2",
>       "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
>       "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
>       "gulp-install": "^1.1.0",
>       "ionic-angular": "3.3.0",
>       "ionicons": "3.0.0",
>       "rxjs": "5.1.1",
>       "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
>       "zone.js": "0.8.11"   },   "devDependencies": {
>       "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
>       "@ionic/cli-plugin-gulp": "1.0.1",
>       "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.1",
>       "gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",
>       "typescript": "2.3.3",
>       "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.0.0",
>
> ```
> "del": "2.2.0",
>
> "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
> "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "^2.0.0",
> "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
> "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
> "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
> "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^2.0.0",
> "run-sequence": "1.1.5"   },   "name": "FancyApplication",   "description": "myFancyApplication: An Ionic project",
> ```
>
> "cordovaPlugins": [
>       "cordova-plugin-device",
>       "cordova-plugin-console",
>       "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
>       "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
>       "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
>       "ionic-plugin-keyboard"   ],
>
> "cordovaPlatforms": [
>       {
>         "platform": "android",
>         "locator": "browser"
>       }   ] }

I already tried to install/uninstall gulp globally also tried to link it. The gulpfile is in the main application folder where it always was. Never moved it.

Did i forgot something to update ? Do i have to move something or do i have to set the attribute? If so i would like to know how.

Thanks already for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by creating a whole new ionic 3 project. Since i was migrating from ionic 1 to ionic 2 already.

Answer (score 1):

i solved my problem.

- npm update
- npm remove gulp-sass
- npm install gulp-sass --save-dev